# Convergence of a series involving arccot?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am supposed to determine the convergence (conditional or absolute) or the divergence of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cot^{-1} ({\pi/4 + n\pi})}{\sqrt{3n^3+1}}$$

I previously solved a similar problem but the function in question was not $\cot^{-1} ({\pi/4 + n\pi})$  but rather $n\tan^{-1} ({\pi/4 + n\pi})$ and that problem was far easier to solve because I concluded that when $n\to+\infty$, $\tan^{-1} ({\pi/4 + n\pi}) \to\pi/2$. Then I used the Limit Comparison Test with the sequence $\frac{1}{n^2}$, and therefore I concluded that the given series absolutely converges. 
***I believe it is important to keep in mind that the denominator in the other problem was different.***

My problem with this series is that from what I could find on the internet $\cot^{-1} ({\pi/4 + n\pi}) \to 0$ as $n\to+\infty$, but by using this line of thinking the whole series will look something like
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{0}{\sqrt{3n^3+1}}$$ which makes no sense at all.
Am I looking at these problems wrong, or is there another value to $\cot^{-1} ({\pi/4 + n\pi})$ as $n\to+\infty$?

Comment: If it really is the arccot, that's bounded, so we get absolute convergence because $|a_n|\lt \frac{K}{n^{3/2}}$ for some constant $K$.

Comment: Are you sure you have the problem right?  $\cot(\pi/4 + n\pi)$ would make sense, and $\cot^{-1}(n)$ but what you have is a strange construction.  Supposing you do have the correct problem, the $\cot^{-1}$ function is bounded, essentially can be discarded.

Comment: @AndréNicolas could you possibly tell me what are the bounds of arccot?

Comment: $-\pi/2$ to $\pi/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$\cot(x)
=\dfrac1{\tan(x)}
$,
so that if
$\tan(x_n)
\to L
$,
then
$\cot(x_n)
\to \dfrac1{L}
$.

Also note that
$\arctan(x)+\text{arccot}(x)
=\pi/2
$.

Therefore
if
$y_n \to \infty$
(as $\pi/4+n\pi$ does),
then
$\arctan(y_n)
\to \pi/2
$
and
$\text{arccot}(y_n)
\to 0
$.

So your result is correct.

Another thing to note:
The whole 
"$\pi/4+n\pi$"
bit is nonsense,
designed to fool you.
Taking the
tan or cot of
"$\pi/4+n\pi$"
might be interesting,
but the inverse tan or cot of this
is just the inverse tan or cot
of a large number,
nothing more.

Comment: Would it be correct to simply conclude that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cot^{-1} ({\pi/4 + n\pi})}{\sqrt{3n^3+1}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{0}{\sqrt{3n^3+1}}$$?

Comment: No because $\cot^{-1} ({\pi/4 + n\pi}) \ne 0$. However $\cot^{-1} ({\pi/4 + n\pi}) \approx 1/ ({\pi/4 + n\pi}) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Thank you! You were extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As n gets large $cot^{-1}(n) \to 1/n.$
and you can run a limit comparison test of

$\frac{\cot^{-1} ({\pi/4 + n\pi})}{\sqrt{3n^3+1}}$vs.$\frac{1}{n\sqrt{3n^3+1}}$

---

The Limit comparison test.
If you have two series $\sum a_n, \sum b_n$ and
$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} |\frac{a_n}{b_n}| = M$ with $M>0$ and bounded. Then either both series converge or both series diverge.

In this case, with $a_n, b_n$ as above: $\frac{a_n}{b_n} = n\cot^{-1}(\pi/4+n\pi)$.

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} n\cot^{-1}(\pi/4+n\pi) = \frac{1}{\pi}$.
Now, can you show that
$\sum\frac{1}{n\sqrt{3n^3+1}}$ converges?

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with this. Could you please elaborate on how this test would be executed?

Comment: sure, see above.

Comment: I understand. For some reason I confused the conditions of convergence of the Limit Comparison Test with the conditions of the Ratio Test. Thank you, you were very helpful!